# Yammer JavaScript SDK : "Expected identifier, string or number"

Tags: javascript, sdk, yammer

I have followed the guidance available from the [JavaScript SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/js-sdk).  I have registered an app and used the supplied **App Id** as indicated in the web page include statement for the SDK:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="...appid..." src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
```

I get the following error when the page loads:

> SCRIPT1028: **Expected identifier, string or number**
>
> File: platform_js_sdk.js, Line: 25, Column: 21658

Can anyone provide insight into why I might be receiving this error?

Comment: [1028](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t19bkk9%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), if IE<10, probably a trailing comma within an object or array literal. Another reason might be an unquoted identifier containing illegal characters.

Comment: Thank you teemu,  I created a simple page:

Comment: Thank you Teemu,  I created a simple page which only has the minimum of html and the include statement.  When I open this page in IE 11 from my PC's hard drive, I get no error.  When I copy the page to a SharePoint site and load it in IE 11 from the SharePoint folder, I get the error reported above.

Comment: IE11 can handle trailing commas in obj/arr literals (but not unquoted illegal characters). I'm not familiar with SharePoint, are you sure the script is really run in IE11 Standards mode, not in any previous IE mode? The error is a parse time error, so it's hard coded to the script file. What you see at line 25 around column 21658?

Comment: Thanks again Teemu. IE11 Debugger shows the following at line 25, Column: 21658 of : 

for:"htmlFor",class:"className"},p‌​rop:function(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g=a.nodeType;if(a&&3!==g&&8!==g&&2!==g)return f=1!==g||!_.isXMLDoc(a),f&&(b=_.propFix[b]||b,e=_.propHooks[b]),void 0!==c?e&&"set"in e&&void 0!==(d=e.set(a,c,b))?d:a[b]=c:e&&"get"in e&&null!==(d=e.get(a,b))?d:a[b]},propHooks:{tabIndex:{get:function(a) 

the Debugger is referencing the beginning of this string starting at "for..."

Comment: Note: the page that is failing is loaded by an Iframe.  the Iframe is located in a parent page which builds the Iframe URL dynamically.  The parent page is loaded in a SharePoint Content Editor web part.  If I load the URL from the Iframe directly in a browser window, I do not get the error.

Comment: There's a `\u200b` character here: `"htmlFor",class:"className"},p‌​[\u200b]rop:function(a,b,c)...`, i.e. an illegal character in a prop name. You can see a red dot at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhsmmypw/).

Comment: Teemu,  in finding this issue, did you open the source file "https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js" or look at what I pasted in my last comment.  If the file has this issue, why am I the only one noticing it?

Answer (score 0):

I left a comment before, but looks like it never got posted.

We are facing same issue, and found the solution and the fix.

SharePoint 2010 master page includes  which causes Yammer API to break. 
Replacing with   fixes it, but we need to test impact on other SharePoint 2010 functionality before we do the change.

Comment: Vinay,  Can you provide more detail.  What is included in the SP2010 master page that causes the issue?  Please provide information regarding your test and the results.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to te use of for as a property name. As for is a reserved keyword in JavaScript:

```
.extend({propFix:{for:"htmlFor",class:"className"}
```

I guess the same will apply for class as of ECMA script 5.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp